# 200 Discs - weighing problem

Tags: logical-deduction, weighing

You are an intrepid explorer who has been caught in a trap by a primitive tribe. They lock you in a room with no exit but one door. The door has a pressure sensitive release - incorrect pressure ($>0g$) will cause immediate death.  There are 10 piles each of 20 heavy stone discs (200 in total). You know what each disc should weigh (I can tell you that the number is in whole grams).

You have some facts:

- You know that one of the piles is made of discs that are missing 15.5 grams of the normal weight of a disc.
- You also know that another distinct pile is made of discs that are missing 6.5 grams of the normal weight.
- You also know that all the discs in all the other piles weigh exactly the right amount.

You have weighing scale (non-balancing) that is accurate to the gram.

The tribe leader has set the rules. You must determine which piles are normal, which pile is off by 15.5 grams and which is off by 6.5 grams using the scale only *once*. Only by putting one disc from each of the 2 piles which are not normal on the pressure pad to release the door will you survive.

Comment: What is "exactly the right amount" or the total weight of a normal pile?

Comment: Not telling....

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Coin weighing problem](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/coin-weighing-problem)?

Comment: @Emrakul It appears to be a slightly more complicated variant

Comment: Is the scale a balancing scale where you put weights on both side, or does it just tell you the weight directly?

Comment: It's not a balancing scale. It tells you the weight directly.

Comment: For "accurate to the gram"- does it consistently round up or down half values? So could 6.5 show up as either 6 or 7, or is it consistently one or the other?

Comment: @BenAaronson It consistently rounds down, sir

Comment: I'd think Joe's answer would work then. I just looked and I can't find any sums of multiples of 6.5 and 15.5 <= 10 which are within 0.5 of each other.

Comment: @BenAaronson You are right. But the answer needs to take all that into account. Although indeed the question should choose the weights more carefully.

Comment: Would be interesting to tweak the numbers to create a version of this where exactly one of the sums of multiples was too close. Then you'd have to make the extra connection that you could avoid one of the pile sizes by weighing no discs at all from a pile

Comment: @BenAaronson Yes, that was the intention actually... it wouldn't be that hard. There must be one or more solutions for the 2 off weights, $i$ and $j$, such that $\lfloor xi \rfloor = \lfloor yj \rfloor \land x \neq y \land 0 < x,y \leq 20$ to cause the ambiguity. And then depending on the method of resolving the situation there would need to be other conditions. I had in mind: no solution for $i$ and $j$, such that $2xi = 2yj \land x \neq y \land 0 < x,y \leq 10$

Comment: I was actually looking for a catch like this, and got confused when I didn't find one xD I assumed I was missing the entire point :-P

Comment: Seems like a spinoff of the sugar cube riddle we had recently. Also, the answer is very much similar.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/find-the-different-sugar-cubes  , and even that is said to be a duplicate of the coin weighing problem, as referenced above.

Comment: @TimCouwelier It's a variation I suppose. Personally I feel that it's different enough to justify its existence. e.g. the numerical complications are greater. I think of it as chess positions being similar but not the same... or knight/knave puzzles being variations of each other (but all interesting)

Comment: Hence me listing it as a spinoff, not a duplicate :)

Comment: @TimCouwelier Yes, I noticed. Thanks Tim ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since we know what each disc should weigh ($n$), we can weigh 1 disc from pile 1, 2 from pile 2, etc (10+9+8... = $55n$). However, since some weights are half-grams, we'll need to double up instead (20+18+16... = $110n$).

Subtract that from the actual weight we read on the scales, then work out how to make the remainder from 13s and 31s. There is no multiple of 13 and 31 which can cause any problems with the math.

This will tell us which piles the abnormal discs came from, so finally just take 1 from each of those piles to put on to the pressure plate.

Comment: Nice, but this won't work because scale is correct to the gram... +1 for now

Comment: Ah ok, so it's going to be something like double the numbers, instead (2, 4, 6...) - I'll take a think when I get up :-P

Comment: lol. good job mate. (but do please complete the answer)

Comment: @d'alar'cop updated the answer for you :-)

Comment: well done :) exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: This is the answer I had in mind at first as well, but for some reason I read that you *didn't* know what each disc is supposed to weigh, so I didn't put it up as an answer.